# String comparison is case sensitive in Expression language?

Tags: el

So just as simple as that. Comparing two strings that differs only for case

```
${"a" == "A"}
```

returns true or false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When two strings are compared in EL, the comparison is always case-sensitive. If you want to do a string comparison that's not case-sensitive, you can just use the equalsIgnoreCase method.

That comparison would return false.

Answer (score 2):

It's case sensitive, so it will return `false`. Another possibility to do a case insensitive comparison of strings is using [JSTL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html):

```
${fn:toLowerCase(stringA) == fn:toLowerCase(stringB)}
```

This is useful for older versions of EL. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info and scroll to "Invoking non-getter methods".